# Find $D$ in RSA cryptosystem

Tags: cryptography

For the following encryption key $(n, E)$ in the RSA cryptosystem, compute $D$.

$(n, E)= (451, 231)$

So I know $n=11*41$, so $m=400$. Now $D=$ inverse of $231 \ (mod \ 400)$. However I am not sure how to find the inverse of $231$ in $mod\ 400$. Help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment, the Euclidean algorithm gives:
\begin{align*}
400 &= 231 \times 1 + 169.\\
231 &= 169 \times 1 + 62.\\
169 &= 62 \times 2 + 45.\\
62 &= 45 \times 1 + 17.\\
45 &= 17 \times 2 + 11.\\
17 &= 11 \times 1 + 6.\\
11 &= 6 \times 1 + 5.\\
6 &= 5 \times 1 + 1.
\end{align*}
Then, we do this in reverse...
\begin{align*}
1 &= 6 - 5\\
&= 6 - (11 - 6)\\
&= 2 \times 6 - 11\\
&= 2 \times (17 - 11) - 11\\
&= ...\\
&= 71 \times 231 - 41 \times 400.
\end{align*}
(Check the details.) Viewing the last equation modulo $400$ gives
$$
231^{-1} \equiv 71 \mod 400.
$$